How to build latest python version from github on termux
I want to install latest version of python on my termux (for some testing) but I couldn't make it. I looked python's readme but it doesn't work. I searched help from ai but it also doesn't work. I tried to understand how termux install python but I couldn't. If somebody tried and make it or have an idea please share it below. Let's make here a guide for building python on termux
Notice: pkg install termux command installs python3.11.9 and i need at least python3.12
Mostly I get this error when I run make command
Python/parking_lot.c:129:15: error: call to undeclared function 'sem_clockwait'; 
ISO C99 and later do not support implicit function declarations [-Wimplicit-function-declaration] 
                                    
129 |         err = sem_clockwait(&sema->platform_sem, CLOCK_MONOTONIC, &ts);

I am not good at C and I don't know what happened here

I think there is a project (nearly official, and for sure discussed officially) about having python on Android. As you see, it is not (yet) so simple. Try to find such project and so the modifications for Android

Type pkg install python -y To Install The Latest Version Of Python In Termux

OP asks for the "latest python version from github", by which I presume they mean version 3.12.5 (at the time of writing). Will this command install that version? Or will it install whatever the latest packaged version is?
